# How to count the number of times a Workflow is triggered in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, workflow

I'm testing a SharePoint List which has been created for ticketing purpose.  We perform post production updates in the DB's we deliver. To track these changes we are using SharePoint List. The list is still under development stage. I had requested for a workflow to copy an item in a list. The Developer provided it. I have tested it and it works fine.  The workflow opens up a modal form with a copy button, and every time the Copy button is clicked the item gets copied.

I had requested the developer to display the number of times the Copy button is clicked on the form to have a track of how many times the item got copied.  But the developer doesn't know how to incorporate this functionality.  Any pointers would be great.

Screenshot for better clarity:
[image]

Few points:

1. I am the end user and not the developer so if my question is not
   making sense please let me know I would try to elaborate.
2. I do not have access to Sharepoint developer or any development
   tools.  I am accessing the Sharepoint through web browser so I would
   request detailed solution if possible.

Answer (score 2):

If the workflow is kicked off when the copy button is clicked, this is a possible solution:

In your list add a column called `CopyCount` of data type `Number` and default value `0`.

Update your workflow to add an activity that increments this column every time the workflow runs.

Now you just need to add this column to your list view to see how many times an item in the list was copied.

Comment: @Gaurav : Thanks for your response.  But your solution would not serve my purpose.  I have added a screenshot to my question for better clarity.  Please let me know if the requirement I have stated is possible in any way.  I do not need the count to be stored anywhere for later use.